# wso2 IS update password allows old password as new password

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2-is-5.1.0.When i use UserAdminStub changePasswordByUser webservice it allows me to use the old password as new password.Is this the expected behaviour or is there any config which can be set so that the wso2 throws an error when both new password and old password are same ?Most of the identity Management does not allow old password to be reset as new password.

Comment: This seems a bug. Can you create JIRA in the https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY

Comment: Think we already have a JIRA       
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2087

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not supported OOTB, you can create a new UserOperatoinEventListner to support this feature.

Thanks
Isura

Answer (score 0):

Since WSO2 IS 5.1.0 does not support this OOTB, one workaround for this can be to implement ***org.wso2.carbon.user.core.listener.UserOperationEventListener*** [1] class's following methods.

**doPreUpdateCredential**

**doPreUpdateCredentialByAdmin**

Here when a user tries to update password or when an admin tries to update the password of  a user, these methods get hit before performing the operation. Here we can do a validation and allow/not-allow the operation. The validation can be to maintain a table in the database for storing passwords (hashed) of the users that are previously set.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/v4.4.3/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/listener/UserOperationEventListener.java